# how to check whether on delete property is set or not in a foreign key constraint in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cascading-deletes

Is there is any query to check whether "`on delete`" property is being set or not set in a foreign key constraint in postgresql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT  UPDATE_RULE, DELETE_RULE
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE   CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_YourForeignKey';
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/52afd/4)**

Answer (score 0):

The [pg_constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) table in the system catalog contains this information. You can query that:

```
select confdeltype from pg_constraint where conrelid=xx and contype='f' and conname='xxxx';
```

The where clauses here are an example - tweak them to suit.

For a portable solution, query [information_schema.table_constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html).